# How to ignore timestamps when creating Zip File?

Tags: c#

I have multiple servers making same task of generating some file/folder data, and need to pack it before callback, then diff it, but stumble across problem in which two identical data folders creating two different archives. Im using this function:

```
ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(...)
```

And this is applied to same data in different folders:

```
C:\a\data\* 
C:\b\data\*
```

Which creates two different zip archives, and only difference is their header and footer. But if I create two archives in from single folder - it is identical. I suppose some timestamps (creation data, modification data, etc) is written to archive.

How one can specify that archives created from same data should be identical? (Ignoring global meta information)

Comment: Umm, can you please tell why you want to close my question?

Comment: You'll probably need to use something like DotNetZip to do this.  None of the `ZipFile` methods allow much configuration of the archive.  And for what it's worth, I have no idea why someone would vote to close this as Too Broad.

Comment: If you want to know if two folders are identical in data only, relying on two ZIP archives to be byte-for-byte identical (save for some bits you filter out) is not a very solid way to do it, even when using the same archiver everywhere. Few of them would be written to guarantee that something like that would be reliable. Even if you got it to work today, it might break tomorrow. Consider storing a bit of metadata (like a compound CRC over all files, or a sorted listed of files and checksums) and comparing that, instead of the archives themselves.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. But this kind of diff is special - it is used to identify duplicates in file system. I don't need content of this zip at all when I need to simply drop it to database. I just need guarantee that this file is one of its kind and unique by content. Look wider. It will not break tomorrow because I don't care about structure of zip file. I care about byte content of 'something' send to file storage. In this case it is archive.

Comment: I think his point is that a hash or CRC would do better for identifying duplicates on the file system, and I agree, using a zip file to accomplish that is overkill and problem-prone.

Comment: I know you don't care about the structure -- my point is that someone might upgrade some software and whoops, it turns out the order of files on disk in the directories suddenly matters and the files are different again. Or whoops, it now uses multiple cores and the blocks are in a different order on every run. Archivers were not *written* to handle this, and produce identical output for situations *you* consider identical. Even if you're zipping *the exact same files*, there is potential for difference. Version control systems *are* written to handle this; archivers aren't.

Comment: First, I don't care if that happens from upgrade to upgrade - whatever, it is not significant that some files will differ from update to update and will be duplicated by program version. Second, if I have kajilion of text files, I don't want to create some per-unit hashes, also I don't want to store this kajilion separately, and send it one by one, then store meta file somewhere. You overcomplicating things while don't know why I choose this approach. Please, consider helping me by providing tips about how I can solve this problem, not how it should be done on supercomputers.

Comment: We are trying to help you by providing tips about how you can solve this problem.  You came here for help - listen to what you receive.

Comment: Actually, that reminds me -- a ZIP file already stores checksums of all individual files. To compare archives, it should be sufficient to compare names and checksums pairwise in alphabetical order, ignoring all other metadata. But otherwise, if you want me to decompile `ZipFile` to see if it's guaranteed to produce identical files for identical input (and if not, how to possibly make it so) -- yeah, not going to do that.

Comment: Ok, I can't do this. Archive should be self presenting for end user. So, no, I need mostly identical archives, and don't have possibility to aggregate it at user end.

Comment: If you're OK with assuming `ZipFile` will yield the same output when presented with the same exact etnries (personally, I'm not) you could manually construct and add `ZipArchiveEntries` to a `ZipArchive` (`ZipArchive.CreateEntry`). Make sure you read the files in a fixed order, assign your own metadata, and there you go. In essence, provide a virtual view over the file system that ensures identical directories give identical results. (I'm not sure you can control time stamps this way, though.)

Answer (score 1):

Well, problem were solver pretty easly by creating archive from folder manually, and setting last modification time of entries:

```
    public static void ZipDirectory(string input, string output, CompressionLevel level)
    {

        input = Path.GetFullPath(input);
        using (var fs = File.OpenWrite(output))
        using (var za = new ZipArchive(fs, ZipArchiveMode.Create))
        {
            foreach (var filePath in Directory.GetFiles(input, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).OrderBy(x => x))
            {
                var name = filePath.Replace(input, "").TrimStart('\\', '/');
                var e = za.CreateEntry(name, level);
                using (var zes = e.Open())
                {
                    using (var fes = File.OpenRead(filePath))
                    {
                        fes.CopyTo(zes);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        using (var za = ZipFile.Open(output, ZipArchiveMode.Update))
        {
            foreach (var e in za.Entries)
            {
                e.LastWriteTime = new DateTimeOffset(1980, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, TimeSpan.Zero);
            }
        }
    }
```

This way my zip archives ignores any unrelevant meta information about files.